# Doctrine 2.0 query cache results can't be used

Tags: doctrine

I'm trying to improve performance of an application using Doctrine 2.0 by utilizing it's result cache.

setResultCacheImpl() and useResultCache(true) on the query are used with APC as cache.

Debugging I can see that `\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->execute` is called but never finds cached data.
Reason is that `$cached[$id]` is never set when data is read from cache. Looking at the Doctrine code below I can also not see how `$cached[$id]` should ever be set:

```
    // Check result cache
    if ($this->_useResultCache && $cacheDriver = $this->getResultCacheDriver()) {
        list($id, $hash) = $this->getResultCacheId();

        $cached = $this->_expireResultCache ? false : $cacheDriver->fetch($id);
        if ($cached === false || !isset($cached[$id])) {
            // Cache miss.
            $stmt = $this->_doExecute();

            $result = $this->_em->getHydrator($this->_hydrationMode)->hydrateAll(
                    $stmt, $this->_resultSetMapping, $this->_hints
                    );
            $cacheDriver->save($id, $result, $this->_resultCacheTTL);

            return $result;
        } else {
            // Cache hit.
            return $cached[$id];
        }
    }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue you need to apply a fix from the Doctrine 2.0.x repository: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/commit/4271706cabdf6f7a99ffbe6aad0efcec1584f562